# How do I find the content for a mini-panel in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a task to edit some content for a footer being used in a Drupal site.  I've got very little experience with Drupal, but I have been able to root around and find stuff here or there over the past few days.  The last time is the footer, and I can't seem to find where the content could be hiding.

In the admin under "panels" I see a "common footer" mini-panel.  When I edit that, it brings me to a screen where I can edit the admin title, admin description, and name (currently common_footer).  I expected a rich text editor where I could edit the body or something to that effect.

In the content list in the admin, I don't see anything that looks like it could be footer content.  Can someone point me in the right direction where to look for this sort of thing?

Comment: My apologies, this is fixed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the current version of mini panels as I cannot find the content edit link either.  To edit the content of a mini panel I had to take the edit url and replace the last "edit" with "content"

For example,
I changed

admin/structure/mini-panels/list/category_landing_right/edit

To

admin/structure/mini-panels/list/category_landing_right/content

Answer (score 7):

There are links to content, context and layout in the top left corner. The problem is that they look like breadcrumbs so they are easy to miss.